# how to reload updated CSV file data in Django

Tags: python, django

I was learning django, where there was a data.csv file.. I learned some commands to load data "python manage.py load_data"  and it worked but when I update the csv file it doesnot show the updated contents. Is there anyone who can tell me about the mistake.. I can provide the code...

Answer (score 0):

To see the changes you would have to delete all the records that where added to the database when you ran that command the first time, make the proper changes to `data.csv` and run the `python manage.py load_data` command again. In this way you will see the updated data.

The `data.csv` file is a file that contains some 'seeds' for the database. When you are running `python manage.py loaddata` - it searches for fixtures and loads the contents in the database. This means that this command will populate the database with the records from `data.csv` file.

#### What’s a “fixture”?

A fixture is a collection of files that contain the serialized contents of the database. Each fixture has a unique name, and the files that comprise the fixture can be distributed over multiple directories, in multiple applications.

Django will search in three locations for fixtures:

1. In the fixtures directory of every installed application
2. In any directory named in the FIXTURE_DIRS setting
3. In the literal path named by the fixture

Django will load any and all fixtures it finds in these locations that match the provided fixture names.

You can read more about loaddata command and fixtures [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata)